# Firestore database, "Error fetching notifications: TypeError: getNotifications is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So! It's my first time sharing my own problems here, so excuse me for the multiple errors and inconsistencies that will follow this message.
I'm working on a ReactJS project that's using Firebase to authenticate users just so the registered ones can send "anonymous gifts" to random users stored in the database. However, and even though the Firestore collections seem to be working nicely, whenever I try to get the data and display it on screen, it says:
"Error fetching notifications: TypeError: getNotifications is not a function"

Here's the code triggering that error:

```
const getNotifications = async (userId) => {
    try {
      const notificationsRef = collection(db, "notifications");
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
        query(notificationsRef, where("recipientId", "==", userId))
      );
  
      const notifications = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const notification = {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        };
        notifications.push(notification);
      });
  
      setNotifications(notifications);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching notifications:", error);
      // Handle the error appropriately
    }
  };
```

Now, allow me to share the code's context:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  updateDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  query,
  where,
  orderBy,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../config/firebase";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

export const CoffeeContext = createContext();

export function CoffeeContextProvider(props) {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [selectedCoffeeType, setSelectedCoffeeType] = useState("");
  const [selectedMessageTemplate, setSelectedMessageTemplate] = useState("");
  const [hostCountry, setHostCountry] = useState("");
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const getRandomRecipient = async () => {
    if (currentUser) {
      const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersRef);
      const users = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

      // Filter out the current user from the list of users
      const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => user.email !== currentUser.email);

      // Select a random user from the filtered list
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredUsers.length);
      const randomUser = filteredUsers[randomIndex];

      if (randomUser) {
        return randomUser.email;
      }
    }

    // If no random user is found or the current user is not available, return null
    return null;
  };

  const sendCoffeeGift = async () => {
    const randomRecipient = await getRandomRecipient();

    if (randomRecipient) {
      try {
        // Create a new coffee gift document in the "coffeeGifts" collection with a random ID
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "coffeeGifts"), {
          coffeeType: selectedCoffeeType,
          messageTemplate: selectedMessageTemplate,
          hostCountry: hostCountry,
          senderId: currentUser.uid,
          recipientId: randomRecipient,
          createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        });

        console.log("Coffee gift sent with ID: ", docRef.id);

        // Create a notification document for the recipient in the "notifications" collection
        await addDoc(collection(db, "notifications"), {
          coffeeGiftId: docRef.id,
          recipientId: randomRecipient,
          senderId: currentUser.uid,
          read: false,
          createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        });

        console.log("Notification created for recipient: ", randomRecipient);

        // Reset the form after sending the coffee gift
        setSelectedCoffeeType("");
        setSelectedMessageTemplate("");
        setHostCountry("");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending coffee gift:", error);
        // Handle the error appropriately
      }
    } else {
      console.error("No random recipient found.");
      // Handle the case when no random recipient is available
    }
  };

  const getNotifications = async (userId) => {
    try {
      const notificationsRef = collection(db, "notifications");
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
        query(notificationsRef, where("recipientId", "==", userId))
      );
  
      const notifications = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const notification = {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        };
        notifications.push(notification);
      });
  
      setNotifications(notifications);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching notifications:", error);
      // Handle the error appropriately
    }
  };

  const markNotificationAsRead = async (notificationId) => {
    try {
      const notificationDocRef = doc(db, "notifications", notificationId);
      await updateDoc(notificationDocRef, {
        read: true,
      });

      const updatedNotifications = notifications.map((notification) =>
        notification.id === notificationId ? { ...notification, read: true } : notification
      );

      setNotifications(updatedNotifications);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error marking notification as read:", error);
      // Handle the error appropriately
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      getNotifications(currentUser.uid);
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <CoffeeContext.Provider
      value={{
        selectedCoffeeType,
        setSelectedCoffeeType,
        selectedMessageTemplate,
        setSelectedMessageTemplate,
        hostCountry,
        setHostCountry,
        sendCoffeeGift,
        notifications,
        markNotificationAsRead,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </CoffeeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As well as the page it's connected to:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../../config/firebase";
import { AuthContext } from "../../../context/AuthContext";
import { CoffeeContext } from "../../../context/CoffeeContext";
import { coffeeTypes, messageTemplates } from "../../../utils/coffeeData";

const Solidarity = () => {
  const {
    selectedCoffeeType,
    setSelectedCoffeeType,
    selectedMessageTemplate,
    setSelectedMessageTemplate,
    hostCountry,
    setHostCountry,
    sendCoffeeGift,
    notifications,
    markNotificationAsRead,
    getNotifications,
  } = useContext(CoffeeContext);

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [selectedCoffeeGift, setSelectedCoffeeGift] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNotifications = async () => {
      try {
        await getNotifications(currentUser.uid); // Call the getNotifications function
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching notifications:", error);
        // Handle the error appropriately
      }
    };

    fetchNotifications();
  }, [currentUser, getNotifications]);

  const handleNotificationClick = async (notificationId) => {
    try {
      await markNotificationAsRead(notificationId);
  
      const coffeeGiftDocRef = doc(db, "coffeeGifts", notificationId);
      console.log("Coffee Gift Document Ref:", coffeeGiftDocRef);
  
      const coffeeGiftDoc = await getDoc(coffeeGiftDocRef);
      console.log("Coffee Gift Document:", coffeeGiftDoc);
  
      if (coffeeGiftDoc.exists()) {
        const coffeeGiftData = coffeeGiftDoc.data();
        console.log("Coffee Gift Data:", coffeeGiftData);
        setSelectedCoffeeGift(coffeeGiftData);
      } else {
        console.log("Coffee Gift Document does not exist.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling notification click:", error);
      // Handle the error appropriately
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await sendCoffeeGift();

    setSelectedCoffeeType("");
    setSelectedMessageTemplate("");
    setHostCountry("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Solidarity</h1>
      <div>
        {notifications.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}></span>
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>New Notification!</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Select Coffee Type:
          <select
            value={selectedCoffeeType}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedCoffeeType(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="">Select Coffee Type</option>
            {coffeeTypes.map((coffeeType) => (
              <option key={coffeeType} value={coffeeType}>
                {coffeeType}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Select Message Template:
          <select
            value={selectedMessageTemplate}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedMessageTemplate(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="">Select Message Template</option>
            {messageTemplates.map((template) => (
              <option key={template} value={template}>
                {template}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Host Country (Optional):
          <input
            type="text"
            value={hostCountry}
            onChange={(e) => setHostCountry(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Send Coffee Gift</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {notifications.map((notification) => (
          <div key={notification.id}>
            <p>{notification.coffeeType}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleNotificationClick(notification.id)}>
              View
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {selectedCoffeeGift && (
        <div>
          <h3>Coffee Received:</h3>
          <p>{selectedCoffeeGift.coffeeType}</p>
          <h3>Message:</h3>
          <p>{selectedCoffeeGift.messageTemplate}</p>
          {selectedCoffeeGift.hostCountry && (
            <>
              <h3>Country:</h3>
              <p>{selectedCoffeeGift.hostCountry}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Solidarity;
```

No matter the many changes, either the users see absolutely nothing, either they see a notification that's empty.
Any ideas of what's wrong (everything, I know) and how to fix it just so the user that's getting the gift can actually fetch the data from a database that's pretending to be nice when it's clearly not?
Thanks a lot, and have a great evening! <3